# Spring Cloud Stream: consume from default Rabbit MQ exchange and specific queue

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

Is it possible to consume via Spring Cloud Stream from some specific queue implicitly bound to the default RabbitMQ exchange?

As I can see in debug in `BindingService.bindConsumer(...)`, `bindingTargets` string array is empty if i specify `destination` as empty string('' in yaml), so no binding consumer(`binder.bindConsumer(...)`) occurs.

My probable workaround is to specify some random destination and set flag `queueNameGroupOnly` to `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the consumer binds a queue `destination.group` to a topic exchange `destination` with routing key `#`.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties).

> **queueNameGroupOnly**
>
> When true, consume from a queue with a name equal to the group. Otherwise the queue name is `destination.group`. This is useful, for example, when using Spring Cloud Stream to consume from an existing RabbitMQ queue.
>
> Default: false.

To consume from an existing queue that is only bound to the default exchange, you need.

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=<doesn't matter, can be omitted; defaults to input>
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=<the name of the queue>
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.bind-queue=false
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.queue-name-group-only=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.declare-exchange=false
```

`queueNameGroupOnly` was specifically added for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, all you need is to specify which destination your 'input' and/or 'output' bindings should be made to. 
You can do so via the following properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=<the name of the input queue>
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=<the name of the input group>

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=<the name of the output exchange>
```

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that; see my answer.